# Output from latch clock

Tags: digital-logic, clock, flipflop

I am using a [74LS377](http://www.skot9000.com/ttl/datasheets/377.pdf) d-type latch but when I connect Vcc and ground, get a 1-1.2V output on the clock pin! I have 4.9V on Vcc and 0V on the ground and enable' pins. For my minimal example, I have left the inputs and outputs floating for a 'minimal example' but have other examples of this behaviour with microcontroller driven inputs. What could be causing this?

EDIT: Following comments I have connected all other input and output pins to ground. I now have a single chip, with the Vcc connected to 4.9V and all other pins except the clock connected to ground. Still reading 1.2V on the clock pin!

Comment: What's a "73-377" exactly? Do you have a proper part number?

Comment: Do you mean a 74xx377 for some value of "xx"? If so, be specific. Some families of TTL have intrinsic pullups on all logic inputs, and what you're seeing is entirely normal.

Comment: 74377 clock is an input not an output? I'm confused.... If you mean your voltmeter or scope measures 1-1.2V on the input that is open, then the meter/scope resistance can not pull it all the way to ground, which is typical TTL.

Comment: Leaving inputs floating is not only bad form , invalid ,  prone to stray parasitic behaviors on the inputs and risky for ESD damage.  Do you know the output current on this voltage or the input/load impedance?  was it a 74HCT377?

Comment: You've already accepted an answer, so it's unclear why you are now asking more questions (accepting an answer effectively marks your question as "answered; no more replies needed"). "*I have connected all other input and output pins to ground*" Unfortunately that is a **bad plan** :-( Somehow you seem to have misunderstood comments about floating *input* pins, and mistakenly thought that you needed to connect *output* pins to ground too. That decision may have damaged your IC. "*Still reading 1.2V on the clock pin!*" Yes, that is expected, since this input pin is still unconnected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a diagram of a TTL Nand gate straight out of Wikipedia. The input buffer for the clock line is going to be the same as this except it will only have one of the two inputs (A or B). You can see that this will tend to pull up the input the exact voltage that you get will depend on a number of factors e.g. voltmeter impedance, characteristics of the input transistor and the values of the other components built into the buffer.

[image: TTL Nand gate]

The point is that this should not be left floating it should be tied to ground or through a pullup to VCC the chip itself will not define the level of an input for you. For any case you need to define all of the logic inputs even for a minimal example.